# How to handle specific hostname like -h option in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm using CentOS 7 as docker daemon host and centos:6 Docker images.

I want to install some software which requires resolvable hostname as non-loopback address. If I run a docker image with -h option like

```
docker run -i -t -h myhost centos:6 /bin/bash
```

Then I can install the software because /etc/hosts in the container automatically configured like

```
[root@myhost /]# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.7  myhost
127.0.0.1   localhost    

[root@myhost /]# ping myhost
PING myhost (172.17.0.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from myhost (172.17.0.7): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
```

But I cannot use same way if I create an image from Dockerfile. I tested creating an image using following Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6

ENV HOSTNAME myhost
RUN ping myhost
```

In docker build process, assigned hostname cannot be resolved as dynamic ip addr like following:

```
$ docker build -t testimage .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM centos:6
 ---> a30bc9f3097e
Step 1 : ENV HOSTNAME myhost
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e73bf592389e
Step 2 : RUN ping myhost
 ---> Running in ca54c8eac073
ping: unknown host myhost
INFO[0000] The command [/bin/sh -c ping myhost] returned a non-zero code: 2
```

How can I use some specific hostname resolved as dynamic container IP addr?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This isn't generally possible in a Dockerfile.

Depending on the software, you might be able to do some kind of work-around. For example, you could try something like

```
RUN echo $(grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts | cut -f1) my.host.name >> /etc/hosts && install-software
```

By setting the hostname within the same RUN command as you install the software, it'll happen inside the same layer of the container. Docker will later overwrite the hostname and you'll have to set it anew when running, but your software might be OK with that.

If you have to do a lot of this, you might try [Packer](https://packer.io/) for building containers. It can build Docker containers, but doesn't use multiple layers. This makes it slower to rebuild, faster to download the built images, and makes it more convenient to do multiple operations on an image before freezing it into a container.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion is truly a work-around what I wanted. I didn't notice that I can edit /etc/hosts if I don't specify -h option, and take effect if I write commands in one RUN step. Also I'll consider to use Packer after Dockerfile trial.

Answer (score 12):

As for workaround, you can use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or `docker stack` to build your container with specific `hostname`, e.g.

```
version: '3'
services:
  all:
    image: testimage
    container_name: myname
    hostname: myhost
    build:
      context: .
```

Then run as:

```
docker-compose --build up
```

or using [Docker stacks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack/):

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml mystack
```

Answer (score 10):

In a case when `/etc/hosts` does not help, I replace the `hostname` binary.

```
RUN mv /usr/bin/hostname{,.bkp}; \
  echo "echo myhost.local" > /usr/bin/hostname; \
  chmod +x /usr/bin/hostname

...

RUN mv /usr/bin/hostname{.bkp,}
```

Comment: it's 2020 :)  i have been reading and testing for hours, and this was the only one that worked. old but gold.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following is better because docker containers usually don't have 'hostname' installed, therefore I would use the head command:

```
echo $(head -1 /etc/hosts | cut -f1) $HOST_NAME >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify hostname during build time, now it implemented under this pull request:
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/1339
You can vote for it to be merged asap.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but ...

Prepare your own script named "hostname" (echoing whatever you want), copy it somewhere into image and in dockerfile insert ENV PATH=:$PATH

It seems to work fine. At least with iRedMail :-)

If needed you may easily extend your script by implementing -a, -f or -d options.

Comment: New PATH should be of the form PATH=path to your hostname script:$PATH of course.

 I used &lt; and &gt; but they disappeared including all between them.