# OS name for docker images

Tags: docker, operating-system, centos, dockerfile

I am trying to build a new docker image using docker provided base Ubuntu image. I'll be using docker file to run few scripts and install applications on the base image. However my script requirement is that the hostname should remain same. I couldn't find any information on OS names for docker images. Does anybody has an idea that once we add layers to a docker image does the OS name remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the hostname with the `-h` argument to Docker run, otherwise it gets the short form of the container ID as the hostname:

```
$ docker run --rm -it debian bash
root@0d36e1b1ac93:/# exit
exit
$ docker run --rm -h myhost -it debian bash
root@myhost:/# exit
exit
```

As far as I know, you can't tell `docker build` to use a given hostname, but see [Dockerfile HOSTNAME Instruction for docker build like docker run -h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157013/dockerfile-hostname-instruction-for-docker-build-like-docker-run-h).

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. But would it remain the same when I'll add layers to it. This one seems to be adding hostname to a running container. When layers would be added through Dockerfile would it be the same.

Comment: No, each layer will have the hostname of the id of the container it ran in. You might be able to manually set it inside the container however.