# Docker build step name cannot start with number

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building a docker image for a Sybase database. `Docker build` command fails because the name of the build step "server" cannot start with a number.

I have searched A LOT for a way to change the build step machine's name and my solution so far is to retry the build until I get a name that starts with a letter...

```
Step 1/7 : FROM my_image as docker_sybase_db
 ---> d266899b4eef
Step 2/7 : COPY *.zip /mnt/backup/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9e8e405848ce
Step 3/7 : COPY entrypoint.sh ~
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c0c923985db
Step 4/7 : ENV HOSTNAME docker_sybase_db
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f2b39a7280a0
Step 5/7 : RUN init_db.sh
 ---> Running in 0ae1a95b3203
Server name '0ae1a95b3203' begins with an illegal character.  The first
character of a server name must be an alphabetic ascii character.
Error running command 'srvbuild -r /tmp/my_super_build.rs':
```

If I can't modify this old sybase init script, am I out of luck here ?

EDIT: Here is what I am trying to do

1. Create a database instance
2. Load a backup
3. Package that pre-loaded instance into a container.

Loading the backup takes a lot of time and this old database system requires the server name to start with a letter, not a number.

Comment: whats inside init_db.sh? I mean why your script take docker layer number as a server name?

Comment: Yes, it's a command from SAP http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1573/html/utilityguide/X12327.htm

Comment: The standard Docker Hub database images don't try to set up the database until the actual container is run.  Could you defer this step until then (using an entrypoint wrapper script to do the initialization if it hasn't been done yet)?  You can then `docker run --hostname` to set what the container believes its hostname is.

Comment: Docker run --hostname is not possible. I need to have run this step in the image build as it takes around 10 minutes of pre-processing that I don't want to have to do each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and see if [LolHens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4380671/lolhens)'s [idea of changing the hostname in the container namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56966401/6309) (during the docker build) works for you.

```sh
docker build . | tee >((grep --line-buffered -Po '(?<=^change-hostname ).*' || true) | \
                       while IFS= read -r id; do \
                         nsenter --target "$(docker inspect -f '{{ .State.Pid }}' "$id")"\
                                 --uts hostname 'new-hostname'; \
                       done)
```

The `docker build` output is parsed to:

- detect a "`change-hostname`" directive
- do a [`nsenter`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html), which runs a program in the [UTS (UNIX Time Sharing) namespace](https://windsock.io/uts-namespace/), with a different hostname (different than the SHA-generated random one)

That means your `RUN` step should be:

```sh
RUN echo "change-hostname $(hostname)"; \
    sleep 1; \
    printf '%s\n' "$(hostname)" > /etc/hostname; \
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$(perl -C -0pe 's/([\s\S]*)\t.*$/$1/m' /etc/hosts)" "$(hostname)" > /etc/hosts; \
    init_db.sh
```

That way, `init_db.sh` should run in an intermediate container with a different hostname (one you do have control over, and which would *not* start with a number).

Comment: I don't think this will work for me, the command needs to work on both windows, linux, TFS and azure devops pipelines. That will make a lot of different commands to support and I don't think I will use this method. That's a seriously creative way of doing it though, wish it worked for me !

Comment: @A_V I was not aware of this multi-platform constraint from reading your original question. It should work everywhere though, through Linux VM where needed.

Comment: This did not work for me and I had to go edit some very old legacy script to get it working on my end but honestly this is creative enough for me to accept the answer. It doesn't get any better than this.