# Docker container hostname

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, hostname, swarm

I'm trying to set docker container hostname (HOSTNAME env var) during startup, this is .sh script specified in ENTRYPOINT of dockerfile:

```
#!/bin/sh
export HOSTNAME=something-$(hostname)
java $JAVA_OPTS  -jar /app.jar
```

I want this new hostname to be seen for jvm.

All I get is standard docker hostname like that:

```
/ # env
HOSTNAME=04dbf311a3be
```

When i set the hostname manually using this export above after the container is started everything works just fine. Everything is being run in swarm using compose stackfile.

**EDIT1:**
I am not doing this during container build but during startup

**EDIT2:**
To be clear, what i have:

DOCKER SWARM:

```
CONTAINER1
HOSTNAME=391fa2c7e184
CONTAINER2
HOSTNAME=39123a43242asd4
CONTAINER3
HOSTNAME=123123123123
```

what i want:

```
CONTAINER1
HOSTNAME=APPNAME-391fa2c7e184
CONTAINER2
HOSTNAME=APPNAME-123fa2c7e184
CONTAINER3
HOSTNAME=APPNAME-343fa345e184
```

And want this to be autmatically set during startup of n-containers

how do i try to achieve this:

I try to set this in start.sh file called on container startup (pointed in ENTRYPOINT command in dockerfile):

```
#!/bin/sh
export HOSTNAME=something-$(hostname)
java $JAVA_OPTS  -jar /app.jar
```

there is no effect, the HOSTNAME is not being changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle specific hostname like -h option in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898787/how-to-handle-specific-hostname-like-h-option-in-dockerfile)

Comment: Not at all, i want to do this after the build - during startup

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the entrypoint script is right place to name your container, as it is already created at that point. You have a couple possibilities. Name it at runtime like this.

```
~
$ docker run -it -h  myContainer 3bee3060bfc8 /bin/bash
[root@myContainer /]# echo $HOSTNAME
myContainer
[root@myContainer /]#
```

The -h option let's you name your container when you run it. 
That value should be valid in your ENTRYPOINT script.

Or, if you want to create your container names more dynamically, you should name them in a docker compose file. Even if you don't use the container_name option, docker-compose will append `-1`

```
version: '2'
services:
  myService:
    container_name: myService-$(envVariable)
```

I don't know swarm, but as it works with a yaml file, you should get similar naming options.

Comment: I call the run.sh script in dockerfile entrypoint command. This sh is placed inside container. I want this to be done automatically for each instance I bring up. What is more - it must be done from inside.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work in swarm mode:


container_name

Specify a custom container name, rather than a generated default name.

container_name: my-web-container

Because Docker container names must be unique, you cannot scale a service beyond 1 container if you have specified a custom name. Attempting to do so results in an error.

    Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file.

Comment: Just to be clear, a container name and the container's hostname are to different things. Setting the container name will not change the hostname, setting the container's hostname will not change the container name. The `docker service create` interface also has --hostname which has parity with the --hostname option on `docker service run`.