# How to prevent docker from assigning new hostname to new containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I have a Dockerfile which will execute a PS script to change the hostname of the container. But when I use "docker run" to start a new container from that image, the container's hostname is changed back to the container ID. The script works from within the container. I want the hostname to stay fixed to what the script has changed during build phase.

I have tried executing the script from within the container and the script works fine. The container hostname gets changed without any errors. But running a container from that image overwrites the hostname.

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer
COPY Test.ps1 .
RUN .\Test.ps1
```

I expect the container hostname to stay fixed from the build phase. The current output is that Docker changes the hostname back to the container ID.

Answer (score 2):

There are many attributes of a Docker container that are only set at runtime.  Most prominently these include published ports and volume mounts, but there are also several other details that are only set at `docker run` time.  Relevantly, nothing you do in the Dockerfile will affect a running container’s hostname: it is always set by the `docker run --hostname` option, or absent this, it is set to the hex container ID.

(Also in this space, a Docker image never has any sort of networking setup or running background processes.)

In most cases you don’t actually care what a container thinks its own hostname is.  Setting the hostname doesn’t affect how other containers are able to reach the container or anything else outside the container, and most programs don’t bother to check their own hostname.  (What should happen if you `docker run --hostname=stackoverflow.com`?)

If you must set the hostname, you have to set it at container launch time, either with the `docker run --hostname` option or the Docker Compose `hostname:` option (or a similar option for a different orchestrator).

Comment: The requirement is that I need to install a particular tool which is licence-bound with that particular hostname. So, I was thinking about using the RUN command to change the hostname AND install the tool on the same layer. Do you have any better solution? The ideal solution would be to fix the hostname of the container OS during the image build phase itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should try add `--name=meaningful_name` to the `docker run` command.

Also, read [that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/naming-docker-containers-3-tips-for-beginners).

Comment: the --name arg sets the container name, not the hostname of the container itself. Also, I am looking for a way to fix the hostname during the docker image build phase itself.

Answer (score 0):

add the `docker-file` container_name value

```
  db:
       image: mysql:5.7
       container_name: mycontainername
       hostname: myhostname
       networks:
           default:
                aliases:
                   myalias
```

Comment: This way, the hostname will be set during the container runtime. I want the hostname to be set during the image build phase.

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898787/how-to-handle-specific-hostname-like-h-option-in-dockerfile