# Docker - How to define IP or hostname during build phase?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, psql

I'm not sure what my next step would be and the different solutions I've tried do not work.

**Background**
I have an application that installs with a BIN file and a configuration file (.properties).
The configuration file contains various configurations for the application. For example database location (hostname/IP), URL to access the application, and so on.
The installation triggers with:

```
bash ./app.bin -s conf.properties
```

The BIN-file connects to the specified database during installation to create a database and user but this part fails and the error message I get is:

```
Create database: failure unable to create database, reason: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to 127.0.0.1:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

[1st screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w5tM.png) & [2nd screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xQAd.png)

**My goal**
My goal is so you can run this container without any variables/environment variables.
But if you want, you should be able to enter your own variables/environment variables such as hostname.

**The question**
It seems that the hostname or IP does not exist during the build phase (docker build) and that is why I'm getting the database connection error.
So how do I fix this? Do I need to put the installation of the BIN-file in the RUN phase (docker run)? And can that even be done?

Any and all ideas here are appreciated very much :)

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM redhat/ubi9:9.0.0 AS RHEL9
LABEL name="Desinger"
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/designer 

# Update system packages
RUN yum -y update

#Install bzip2
RUN yum install bzip2 -y

#Install PostgreSQL
RUN dnf install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-9-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
RUN dnf install -y postgresql14-server
RUN systemctl enable postgresql-14

#Copy OO files
COPY files/installer-designer.bin /usr/local/designer
COPY files/designer.properties /usr/local/designer
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/designer/installer-designer.bin

#Copy other filers
COPY files/ls /usr/bin/ls
COPY files/sudo /usr/bin/sudo
COPY files/hostname /usr/bin/hostname
COPY files/nano /usr/bin/nano

#Environment variables 
ENV ADMIN=admin
ENV PASS=?Password_123

#Expose ports
EXPOSE 8445
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5432 

# Replace placeholders in configuration file with environment variables
RUN sed -i 's/${ADMIN}/'"$ADMIN"'/' /usr/local/designer/designer.properties
RUN sed -i 's/${PASS}/'"$PASS"'/' /usr/local/designer/designer.properties

# Install Designer
RUN bash /usr/local/designer/installer-designer.bin -s /usr/local/designer/designer.properties
```

I've tried the following without any success

- **echo $(head -1 /etc/hosts | cut -f1) $HOST_NAME >> /etc/hosts**
  Source: [How to handle specific hostname like -h option in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898787/how-to-handle-specific-hostname-like-h-option-in-dockerfile)
- **ENV HOSTNAME="foo"

  RUN echo "foo" > /etc/hostname**
  Source: https://forums.docker.com/t/customizing-hostname-during-docker-build-phase/13029/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You intrinsically can't fix these details at image-build time.  Consider that it's possible to run multiple copies of an image in separate containers, and each will have its own IP address.

That means, when the container starts up, you need to rewrite the configuration file and run the installer.  (Hopefully this is not an expensive process.)  Write a short shell script to do this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Replace placeholders in configuration file with environment variables
sed -i.bak 's/${ADMIN}/'"$ADMIN"'/' /usr/local/designer/designer.properties
sed -i.bak 's/${PASS}/'"$PASS"'/' /usr/local/designer/designer.properties
# You also may need to substitute the database host name here
# (Would envsubst(1) help you?)

# Install Designer
/usr/local/designer/installer-designer.bin -s /usr/local/designer/designer.properties

# Switch to the main container command
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, make sure to `COPY` this script in, and make it be the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.

---

A brief pause:

A container normally only runs a single process.  Commands like `service` or `systemctl` tend to not work.  You can't start a background process in a Dockerfile; the `RUN systemctl` line will probably fail because a `systemd` isn't running.  It's routine to run a database as a separate container, maybe using a separate [`postgres`](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) container.

Setting the application to connect to 127.0.0.1 will tell it to try to connect to its own container.  It seems like you're expecting the database to run there too; since it's not, that could be the cause of your connection error.

You also don't need to `COPY` basic utilities like `ls` into the container; and you don't usually need `sudo` in Docker at all.

---

With this in mind, we should be able to reduce the Dockerfile to just:

```bash
FROM redhat/ubi9:9.0.0 AS RHEL9
LABEL name="Desinger"

#Install bzip2
RUN yum install bzip2 -y

#Copy OO files
WORKDIR /usr/local/designer
COPY files/installer-designer.bin files/designer.properties files/entrypoint ./
RUN chmod +x installer-designer.bin entrypoint

#Document the application port
EXPOSE 8445

#Defaults to run the container
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/designer/entrypoint"]
CMD ["/usr/local/designer/designer"]
```

Since we need to run two containers, this is a setup that will work well using Docker Compose.  A basic Compose setup can look like:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  designer:
    build: .
    ports:
      # first port is any available host port
      # second port _must_ be 8445, matching the image
      - '8445:8445'
    environment:
      PGHOST: database # matches Compose service name below
      ADMIN: $DATABASE_USER
      PASS: $DATABASE_PASSWORD
  database:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: $DATABASE_USER
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DATABASE_PASSWORD
volumes:
  database_data: # empty
```

You also will need to create a `.env` file that includes the username and password (pick better values than these):

```bash
DATABASE_USER=admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=passw0rd
```

Comment: How would I get the IP/hostname from the Postgre/database container?
I need it in the designer.properties file so the installation knows where the database is.
I've googled around but I still don't see a solution

Comment: The Compose service name `database` is usable as a host name from other containers in the same Compose file; the environment setting `PGHOST: database` points at it.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  (You do not need to manually assign `networks:`, `container_name:`, or `hostname:` for this to work.)

Comment: I've been testing and googling but I can't figure out how to get the hostname/IP of the PostgreSQL database into the config file. The error message from the installations says it's trying to contact localhost:5432 which is wrong. My docker-compose file has "environment:
      PGHOST: database" and my script has "sed -i.bak 's/${PGHOST}/'"$PGHOST"'/' /usr/local/designer/designer.properties
"

Comment: One nice thing about the entrypoint-wrapper setup is that you can `docker-compose run designer cat /usr/local/designer/designer.properties`.  The `cat` command replaces the image's command but not the entrypoint, so the wrapper script runs, does its substitutions, and then switches to `cat` as the main container process, which will dump out the config file and exit immediately.  Are the file contents correct?

Comment: No, the database host is empty in the designer.properties file

Comment: Please forget my last comment. I used the docker command instead of the docker-compose command